# Drop down third party form linked through iframe when image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Basically I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to setup an image such that when the user clicks an image - a third party form that is currently linked in the html as iframe src="" drops down below said image and then collapses when the image is clicked again. I have tried different variations using jquery but I can't seem to figure it out. I feel like it should be simple to do but I am having 0 luck. Any of the other suggestions I've seen have been related to YouTube thumbnails and playing a video on click which isn't really what I'm looking to do.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern with vanilla JS meets your specifications.
It can probably be enhanced with jQuery (e.g. I know jQuery has a .toggle method and a .slideDown method).

```js
function toggleIframe(){
  const frame = document.getElementById("myIframe");
  if(frame.style.display != "block"){ frame.style.display = "block"; }
  else{ frame.style.display = "none"; }
}
```

```css
#container{ position: relative; }
#myImg{ height: 100px; width: 300px; border: solid 1px gray; }
#myIframe{ height: 100px; width: 300px; border: solid 1px gray; display: none; }
#rest-of-page{ position: absolute; top: 100px; height: 200px; width: 500px; border: solid 1px gray; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="myImg" onclick="toggleIframe()">img</div>
  <div id="myIframe">iframe</div>
  <div id="rest-of-page"><br/><br/>rest of page</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! The secret sauce, as you can probably see in the code, includes 1)Invoking a function that toggles the `display` property of `myIframe`'s style attribute when the user clicks `myImg`, and 2)Setting the `position` property of `rest-of-page`'s style attribute to "absolute" (inside a relative-positioned ancestor) so the whole rest-of-page doesn't shift down when the function is called, and 3)Using the `top` property of `rest-of-page`'s style attribute to offset it vertically from the top of its positioned ancestor if needed.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the explanation, it is very much appreciated!